# React mobx cannot find the injected store

Tags: typescript, mobx, mobx-react, react-tsx

I bind a click event to the checkbox, which will call the action function in the store. However, when I click the checkbox, the store doesn't seem to be injected.

I bind the click event on checkbox. The `CheckBox.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { Checkbox, Stack } from '@fluentui/react';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';

import { PageStore } from '../Store/PageStore';

interface CheckBoxSexProps {
    pageStore?: PageStore
}

@inject("pageStore") @observer
export class CheckBoxSex extends React.Component<CheckBoxSexProps, {}> {

    // Used to add spacing between checkboxes
    private stackTokens = { childrenGap: 10 };
    private changeType: string = "female";

    public render() {
        console.log("CheckBoxSex render");
        console.log(this.props.pageStore);
        return (
            this.props.pageStore?.loadingStatus ?
                <Stack tokens={this.stackTokens}>
                    <Checkbox label="female" defaultChecked onChange={this.onChange("female")} />
                    <Checkbox label="male" defaultChecked onChange={this.onChange("male")} />
                </Stack>
                : null
        );
    }

    private onChange = (sexType: string) => {
        this.changeType = sexType;
        return this._onChange;
    }

    private _onChange(ev?: React.FormEvent<HTMLElement | HTMLInputElement>, isChecked?: boolean) {
        this.props.pageStore?.changeFilter(this.changeType, isChecked);
    }
}
```

And the store has been exported. The `PageStore.ts`

```
import { action, computed, makeObservable, observable } from 'mobx';

export class PageStore {

    @observable public filter: Set<String> = new Set(["female", "male"]);

    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this);
    }

    @action
    public changeFilter(sex: string, actionType: boolean | undefined) {
        if (actionType) {
            this.filter.add(sex);
        } else {
            this.filter.delete(sex);
        }
        console.log(actionType)
    }
}
```

And I provide the store in `Canvas.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';

import {Provider, observer} from 'mobx-react'

import { CheckBoxSex } from './CheckBox_Class';
import { DetailsInfo } from './DetailsInfo_Class';
import { PageStore } from '../Store/PageStore';

@observer
export class Canvas extends React.Component {

    private pageStore: PageStore;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.pageStore = new PageStore(); 
         
    }

    public render() {
        console.log("Canvas render");
        return (
            this.pageStore?.loadingStatus === true ? 
                <Provider pageStore={this.pageStore}>
                    <div className="ms-Grid" dir="ltr">
                        <div className="ms-Grid-row">
                            <div className="ms-Grid-col ms-sm6 ms-md4 ms-lg3">
                                <DetailsInfo />
                            </div>
                            <div className="ms-Grid-col ms-sm6 ms-md8 ms-lg9">
                                <CheckBoxSex />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Provider>
                : null
        );
    }

}
```

The problem is that the page can be rendered,  but once I click the checkbox it will raise an error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.pageStore')
> _onChange

Comment: Can you try to make `_onChange` an arrow function? I think it losing context there. `private _onChange = (ev?: React.FormEvent<HTMLElement | HTMLInputElement>, isChecked?: boolean) => { ...`

Comment: Arrow function works! In normal function, `this` represents the checkbox component. And `this` represents the entire class component in arrow function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to make `_onChange` an arrow function? I think it losing context. Like that:

```js
    private _onChange = (ev?: React.FormEvent<HTMLElement | HTMLInputElement>, isChecked?: boolean) => {
        this.props.pageStore?.changeFilter(this.changeType, isChecked);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I read some documents. `this` in arrow function is where it is defined, while `this` in normal function is where it is called.